# Display test-connection successes and failures in Out-Gridview

Tags: powershell, if-statement, wmi, out-gridview

I am trying to get a list of servers and the last time they rebooted to show in a table. However, if it doesn't respond to a ping, I just need it to show in the list. I can't seem to figure out how to get it to add to the table after `else`.

```
Import-CSV $Downtime | % {
if(Test-Connection $_.server -Quiet -count 1){
    Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $_.server | 
    select @{LABEL="Name"; EXPRESSION = {$_.PSComputerName}}, @{LABEL="Last Bootup"; EXPRESSION = {$_.convertToDateTime($_.LastBootupTime)}}
    }
else{@{LABEL="Name"; EXPRESSION = {$_.server}}
    }
} | Out-GridView
```

I can always save the else results in a text file but this would be more convenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the same object, with the same properties!, in both cases so that PowerShell will understand the association between the two. The follwing example builds a custom hashtable using the if/else and outputs the object for each loop pass.

```
Import-CSV $Downtime | ForEach-Object {
    $props = @{}
    $server = $_.server
    if(Test-Connection $server -Quiet -count 1){
        $wmi= Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $server 
        $props.Name = $wmi.PSComputerName 
        $props."Last Bootup" = $wmi.convertToDateTime($wmi.LastBootupTime)
    }else{
        $props.Name = $server
        $props."Last Bootup" = "Could not contact"
    }
    New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $props
} | Out-GridView
```

I used `$server` as the $_ changes context a couple of time so we wanted to be able to refer to the current row in the CSV we are processing.

I don't know what your PowerShell version is so I will assume 2.0 and create objects that support that.

In both cases an object is created with a `Name` and `Last Bootup` property which is populated based on the success of the ping.

[image: Sample Output]

As an aside [I had a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519623/create-a-blank-object-for-test-connection) a while ago about created similar object based output.